# How to make silverlight date picker disable?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I want to make date picker control disable in silverlight . date should be entered from code side . how to do ? any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use IsEnabled functionality of Silverlight [DatePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datepicker%28VS.95%29.aspx) like follows

```
<control IsEnabled="false"/>
```